# How to sum unique values of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'y': 2019, 'pop': 234}, {'y': 2018, 'pop': 23}, {'y': 2017, 'pop': 2444}, {'y': 2018, 'pop': 12}, {'y': 2019, 'pop': 22}])
```

I want to create a new dataframe where the `pop` is summed based on the year:

```
years = df['y'].unique()    
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'y': 2019, 'pop': 256}, {'y': 2018, 'pop': 35}, {'y': 2017, 'pop': 2444}])
```

Comment: look in to --> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: `df.groupby(['y']).sum()`

Comment: Also: `df.pivot_table(values='pop', index='y', aggfunc='sum')`